# Java code regex not working

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to add a validation utility to a program I have already created. This utility will analyze a file to ensure it meets proper parameters. I have finished the analysis for the first line and am running into a problem regarding whitespaces. The file that I am using for testing includes this line:

```
1459875655257 05112345678945612345678941EMMAM                  BANK OF AMERICA, NA    BAC
```

The block of code that tests this line and is generating the problem is as follows:

```
  if(immediateDestName.isEmpty()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
      "ERROR: File header immediate destination name is missing!");
  } else {
    if((sCurrentLine.substring(40,63)).matches("A-Za-z0-9 ]+")){
    }else{
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
         "ERROR: File header immediate destination name is invalid: "
         +sCurrentLine.substring(40,63));
    }
  }
```

When I run the validation utility it pops open that JOptionPane, suggesting that the name is invalid. Just FYI the actual substring is EMMAM followed by a bunch of whitespaces (hence the problem).

Can someone please help me figure out why my program is flagging this alert even though from all I can see the substring matches the regex?

Comment: `A-Za-z0-9 ]`, is the missing `[` a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
if (sCurrentLine.substring(40,63).matches("[A-Za-z0-9 ]+")) { .. }
```

I believe you missed the first bracket. This will match any character that is `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` or a space.

Comment: Oh my god I feel like such an idiot. 

Thanks though. I had went over it again and again but did not see that..

Sometimes it takes a second set of eyes to notice the obvious though.. Don't think I deserved a down vote for that though.